# qemu-system-x86_64 not found when moving VMs between computers

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, virsh, gnome-boxes, guixsd

I am moving GNOME Boxes virtual machines from Fedora to Guix following [the guide on Fedora wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Move_boxes_virtual_machines).

On the Fedora workstation:

```
$ virsh list --all
 Id   Name           State
-------------------------------
 -    win10          shut off
$ cd ~
$ virsh dumpxml win10 >win10.xml
$ mv .local/share/gnome-boxes/images/win10 win10
```

Then, I moved `win10` and `win10.xml` to the home directory at the new machine. On that Guix system:

```
$ guix install gnome-boxes
$ cd ~
$ mv win10 .local/share/gnome-boxes/images/win10
$ guix install libvirt
$ virsh create win10.xml
error: Failed to create domain from win10.xml
error: Cannot check QEMU binary /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64: No such file or directory
```

`qemu-system-x84_64` is located in a different place:

```
$ type qemu-system-x86_64
qemu-system-x86_64 is /run/current-system/profile/bin/qemu-system-x86_64
```

So, how do I complete importing the virtual machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to `qemu-system-x86_64` is specified in the XML file. Open it in an editor of your choice, find the place where the path is specified and adjust it according to the path on your system. On a Guix system, the path should be:

```xml
<domain type='kvm'>
  …
  <devices>
    <emulator>/run/current-system/profile/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    …
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='selinux' relabel='yes'/>
</domain>
```

But this will bring the next error message when trying `virsh create` on the edited XML file:

```
$ virsh create win10.xml
error: Failed to create domain from win10.xml
error: unsupported configuration: Security driver model 'selinux' is not available
```

Open the XML file again and remove the line mentioning `selinux`. Try `virsh create` on your XML file again and it should create the virtual machine this time. Be ready that the machine may start right away in the background.